# PictureBox and Paint Event

Tags: c#, winforms, events, picturebox

I have a picturebox, let's say "PB". I catch the paint event of PB in

```
private void PB_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
```

In PB_Paint, I draw some shapes.

I would like to control who calls this method.
For example, when the Form is resized or other thing, they call PB.Invalidate() which call PB_Paint.
Why I want to control who call this method ? Because, I want PB_Paint to be called only when I want.

I thought to control who calls PB_Paint, inside PB_Paint and before the draw process, and make a Switch... But "sender" is always PB and PaintEventArgs does not give any information to know who is the caller.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Not very clear, but try doing your painting to a bitmap and then just use the PictureBox to display that bitmap.

Comment: You call Invalidate whenever you have made changes to the data that control what you paint in the Paint event. Maybe in the MouseMove event, when you have collected a new coordinates.. The system __needs__ to call it sometimes. Why would you stop __necessary__ updates?? The result would the display errors!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add flag (e.g. `f_paint_enabled`) in the beginning of PB_Paint and enable/disable it to control the task.

Comment: Yes, I think it's the best thing I can do.